# Why is using the this keyword in TypeScript classes static methods allowed?

Tags: typescript

The following code is a TypeScript code representing a bug that happens if you use the `this` keyword inside a static method, even though it passes the compiler checker:

```
class Example{
    static foo():string{
        return this.bar();
    }

    static bar():string{
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Broken{
    static breaksThis(callback: () => string):string{
        return callback();
    }
}

console.log(Example.foo()); // works
console.log(Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo)); // Error at line 3: "this is undefined"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTA3gKGn6EALmIQJbDQBmA9tQBQCUAXEQE6kB2A5jvn9K3SEArqw7RCAC1IQAdACMwrRgG5c+AL7Z1eIiXLRFy5m048d-QSLHQAREdtq+WrdlCQYAIVbUA1ug5efD0yCnlBMF8IABVpCDpgMBAQRWBfJmhGaABeAD4CQnZuE0KzIP4BIVFxROTU31ULF21gag4IagxZEGouOgRkNHRZGnoGBhVoAHop6AB3alYotzaOrp6+7z8AhQio2Jl+xFQu0fHJmbhWH1ZoEmgQTnRoAGYM2ykZaC-hDgATdCUJ5-Wx).

The problem is that on line 3, `this` refers when calling it the first time to the class itself. Which is what VS Code will show you when you hover over `this`.

```
Example.foo() // $this on line 3 is Example.
```

However, in the second time running this code, `this` will be `undefined`.

```
Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo) // $this on line 3 is undefined.
```

The solution to the above code is pretty simple, just replace `this` on line 3 with the actual class name as follows:

```
class Example{
    static foo():string{
        return Example.bar();
    }

    static bar():string{
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Broken{
    static breaksThis(callback: () => string):string{
        return callback();
    }
}

console.log(Example.foo()); // works
console.log(Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo)); // works
```

Since it's recommended (based on what I saw) to **always** replace any occurrence of the word `this` inside any static method with the class name itself to avoid this kind of bug, why does TypeScript allow us to set the `this` keyword inside a static method when it's forbidden in JavaScript?

Comment: It's not specific to static methods ; it has to do with the fact that TS doesn't strictly check `this` for functions in general.  There's a longstanding open issue at [ms/TS#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) about it. See the linked q/a above for more information

Comment: "*Since it's recommended (based on what I saw) to always replace any occurrence of the word this inside any static method with the class name itself to avoid this kind of bug*" I certainly wouldn't recommend that. The recommendation seems like it's coming from a source unfamiliar with [how the `this` keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and it's reactionary rather than well-informed. Trying to restrict the path to failures (and proper usages) rather than actually understand what is improper.